# What is "qs=0.001" in the Content-Type header?

Tags: mime-types, content-type

I am checking the content-type header to determine if a page is a PDF or not.

Typically, a PDF will give me a content type of `application/pdf`. However, the page: https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf

shows me: `content-type: application/pdf; qs=0.001`

What is `qs=0.001`? I didn't find any references to it in the [specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3778.txt).

Should I replace my `contentType === "application/pdf"` check with `contentType === "application/pdf" || contentType.startsWith("application/pdf;")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find this
https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2002AprJun/0037.html

Looks like it is on HTTP level.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, my searches included both "qs" and "application/pdf" so I missed this. I will give it a read and try to make sense of it.

Comment: seems like it shouldn't be included on the header as per "Of course,
the "qs" parameter should not be included in the Content-Type header"

Comment: No it is not necessary to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this comes from [Apache HTTP Server (httpd)](https://httpd.apache.org/). The server has type-map file concept. This file contains a mapping of the files and their MIME types. In the [Negotiation in httpd](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/content-negotiation.html#negotiation) section it states:

> If the variants have different source qualities, that may be indicated by the "qs" parameter to the media type, as in this picture (available as JPEG, GIF, or ASCII-art):
>
> ```
> URI: foo
>
> URI: foo.jpeg
> Content-type: image/jpeg; qs=0.8
>
> URI: foo.gif
> Content-type: image/gif; qs=0.5
>
> URI: foo.txt
> Content-type: text/plain; qs=0.01
> ```
>
> qs values can vary in the range 0.000 to 1.000. Note that any variant with a qs value of 0.000 will never be chosen. Variants with no 'qs' parameter value are given a qs factor of 1.0. The qs parameter indicates the relative 'quality' of this variant compared to the other available variants, independent of the client's capabilities. For example, a JPEG file is usually of higher source quality than an ASCII file if it is attempting to represent a photograph. However, if the resource being represented is an original ASCII art, then an ASCII representation would have a higher source quality than a JPEG representation. A qs value is therefore specific to a given variant depending on the nature of the resource it represents.

Thus, `qs` specifies the relative quality of the pdf file as compared to other file formats representing the same thing. As far as I know this `qs` parameter is `httpd` specific, so it should be relatively safe to ignore it.

You might Apache Administrator's Handbook, page 112-113 (e.g., in Google Books [preview](https://books.google.lt/books?id=gSd0UQ8bAWgC&pg=PA113&lpg=PA113)) slightly more readable than the docs on the matter of  type-map and `qs` parameter.